# How to do Complex Querying with Firebase?

Tags: firebase, web-applications, firebase-realtime-database, nosql

I'm creating my first app in Firebase.  I have no experience with NoSQL, so working out my data structure is proving to be a challenge.  Let's say my app is similar Reddit where users visit the site and read/write posts.  I want the app to have a list view where it sorts the post data in several ways, however it is all centered around the date posts where submitted:

#### Views

1. Show the latest posts in descending order.
2. Show the latest posts for a specific tag.
3. Show the most liked posts in descending order for the last day (24 hours).

I assume the data structure to look this:

```
{
    "posts": {
        "post_0": {
            "content": "...",
            "created_at": 1497112445748,
            "likes": 100,
            "tags": {
                "tag_0": true,
                "tag_2": true
            }
        },
        "post_1": {
            "content": "...",
            "created_at": 1497112549374,
            "likes": 30,
            "tags": {
                "tag_1": true
            }
        },
        "post_2": {
            "content": "...",
            "created_at": 1497112640376,
            "likes": 70,
            "tags": {
                "tag_1": true,
                "tag_2": true
            }
        },
        ...
    }
}
```

#### View 1

This is probably the easiest to resolve.  I imagine the script to retrieve the data would be something like this:

```
const ref = firebase.database().ref("posts");
const query = ref.orderByChild("created_at").limitToLast(50);
query.on("child_added", (snapshot) => {
    // Do stuff like add to array for sorting
});
```

#### View 2

This is where things get tricky.  Since you can only have one `orderBy*` per query, the only way I can see to pull this off is to have a tags node that duplicates the date and post ID.  For example:

```
{
    "tags": {
        "tag_2": {
            "post_0": {
                "created_at": 1497112445748
            },
            "post_2": {
                "created_at": 1497112640376,
            }
        },
        ...
    }
}
```

I've read this is the whole concept of denormalization and structuring your data around your views, but isn't there a better way?

#### View 3

I don't know how to solve this one at all.  As the last 1 day is changing every time the view is requested and the likes are fluctuating often, how can I possibly structure my data around this view?

I've read that push keys, which would take place of the `post_n` key I have in my example, are sequential and can somewhat be relied on as a timestamp.  I'm not sure if there's some way to take advantage of that.

---

I've found a few useful videos by the Firebase team and articles on Medium, but I'm afraid they don't go far enough for me to understand how to accomplish the needs of my app.

- [Common SQL Queries converted for the Firebase Database](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sKFLI5FOOHs&index=4&list=PLl-K7zZEsYLlP-k-RKFa7RyNPa9_wCH2s)
- [Firebase Data Structures: Pagination](https://howtofirebase.com/firebase-data-structures-pagination-96c16ffdb5ca)

I'm just find this aspect of Firebase really confusing to get my head around to have it return the data I need for my views.

If anybody can provide me with an example of how to accomplish these things, it would be much appreciated!  Thanks!

Comment: For #3, i would get all posts within 24 hours, and then sort by likes on the client. You could also write a cloud function that maintains a separate node of most liked posts in last 24 hours.

Comment: I thought about that, having a cloud function running daily or even hourly getting all posts for the last 24 hours.  However, it wouldn't be truly "the last 24 hours", so I was hoping there might be another way.

Comment: Well the cloud function could be called every time a like occurs, so it would be real time.

Comment: You ever figure out #3?  I am trying to recreate that exact issue but its really tricky

Comment: Yes, but mind you I haven't had a chance to implement it yet. As I see it, you would have to create an hourly cloud function cron job with NodeJS that duplicates all posts for the last 24 hours. Then you can sort that by number of likes. As I've come to learn, duplicating data to make fetching or specific queries easier is just part of the NoSQL methodology. You can use cloud functions to help process and maintain data as needed. So, reading and queries become easier at the expense of writing/updating becoming more complex.